# Was the 2019 Lion King film made through motion capture?

Tags: film-techniques, the-lion-king-2019

In the movie *The Jungle Book*, Favreau utilized motion capture with certain actors, expressing a desire to avoid overusing the technology in order to prevent evoking an uncanny valley effect. This is a reference from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jungle_Book_(2016_film)#Filming_and_visual_effects).

I wonder if *The Lion King (2019)* movie has used motion capture. If some scenes have used motion capture in the movie, what are those scenes?

<sub>I couldn't find any authentic source confirming that Lion King was made with performance capture.</sub>

Comment: You say you have a reference from Wikipedia, but then don't provide it. Would you like to complete your post with an edit?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The simple answer is no, it's not motion captured. But there is even confusion about it being considered live-action or animated for award nominations.

From [vanityfair](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2019/05/lion-king-animated-or-live-action-jon-favreau):

> Disney’s upcoming Lion King adaptation has reached a slight hurdle. The film, a remake of the 1994 animated classic, is not exactly a “live-action” movie because all of its animals are computer-generated, though plenty of people and media outlets have called it that. But director Jon Favreau also argues that it isn’t technically right to label the film “animated“ either
>
> > “Well, it’s difficult because it’s neither, really,” he told SlashFilm. “It depends what standard you’re using. Because there’s no real animals and there’s no real cameras and **there’s not even any performance that’s being captured** that’s underlying data that’s real. Everything is coming through the hands of artists.”

For additional trivial information, there was one scene in the film which was not made on computers as per Favreau's [tweet](https://twitter.com/Jon_Favreau/status/1154837688656134144):

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97272/discussion-on-answer-by-ankit-sharma-was-the-2019-lion-king-film-made-through-mo).

Comment: Based on the quotes above I’m wondering why there is any ambiguity as to its status. Surely it’s an animated film in the same vane as Pixar films etc?

Answer (score 13):

In an interview with [Collider](http://collider.com/the-lion-king-jon-favreau-interview/), Jon Favreau said:

> ...we don’t do motion capture for performance, because we don’t want
>   to do it. We don’t want to put markers on animals, we don’t want to
>   involve live action, live animals in this. In Jungle Book, we didn’t
>   have to. I think that’s a nice next step for movies, is to leave the
>   animals alone.

and

> What we’ll do for performance is I’ll have the actors in this room, we
>   clear it out, it’s a soundproof room. We have microphones, and instead
>   of recording with music stands and a sound booth like we do in
>   animated movies, I’ll instead have them performing standing up, almost
>   like you would in a motion capture stage, except no tracking markers,
>   no data, no metadata’s being recorded. It’s only long-lens video
>   cameras to get their faces and performances, and that allows the mall *[sic]*
>   to overlap and perform together and improvise and do whatever we want.